# Recommend a good .NET 4.0/SQL Server 2008 web host (shared platform)

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting, .net-4.0

This is my first question so play nice!!! I've done a search and could only find similar questions relating to .NET 3.5 last year so I thought I'd ask for people's recommendations at this point in time regarding a good web host to use for a small e-commerce website that will run on .NET 4.0 with a SQL Server 2008 back end.

Opinions on hosts seem to change daily as do their offers and the technology that they support so I'd love to hear what people are using at this time and how they're getting on. I generally run everything through GoDaddy but their Shared hosting packages only support SQL Server 2005 at the moment, I called them and to get access to a SQL Server 2008 database you have to go down the Virtual Server route which will cost too much for this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything specific in terms of non-functional requirements that you are looking for other than technology. I.E., level of data centre security, cost, bandwith allowance, redundancy, SLAs etc?

Comment: Isn't this a serverfault question not a programming Stackoverflow question?

Comment: With regards other non-functional requirements, cost is obviously a big factor. GoDaddy offer a shared account for approx £5/month which sounds about right to me, that comes with unlimited bandwidth and 150MB of storage which should be sufficient.

Comment: I've cross posted this on serverfault as recommended - http://serverfault.com/questions/196099/recommend-a-good-net-4-0-sql-server-2008-web-host-shared-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with WinHost in the end and am now up and running. Setup, at least was faultless. http://www.winhost.com/windows-hosting-plans.aspx